In what way do שחוק and קלות ראש bring to ערוה?
In Kitzur Shulchan Oruch, 29:6, we learn about the "kitzur middos" that a person should keep to. One of them is:

"Schok and kallus rosh bring a person to erva".

This is directed by the Kitzur Shulchan Oruch to regular people, in regular situations - nothing to do with interactions with women.

What classifies as "kallus rosh"?
Whatever the answer might be, how the heck does that equal erva? Nothing to do with women!!

(Possible source for question 1:
Shulchan Oruch in Hilchos Nida, YD 195:1 says, one of the harchokos is that it is ossur to have schok and kallus rosh. The Shach (loc sit) explains:  "Devorim hamargilim le'erva".
Now, there at least I can attempt to understand the connection to erva, being that a person has a strong relationship with his wife and during the days of tumah he is suppressing himself, some sort of lightheaded conduct might bring him to erva.
But... how would that translate to a case where no women are involved..?!)
Even worse, the poskim there (YD 195:1) talk about all sorts of innocuous games like chess and ping-pong as examples of kallus rosh. I just thought that they are ignoring the explicit shach, who specifies "Devorim hamargilim le'erva". But now I see the shach is not qualifying which type of kallus rosh. The shach is just bringing the words of chazal, that ALL kallus rosh brings to erva.
So bizarrely it would appear that if you join the dots, all these poskim would say that two friends playing chess are engaged in "kallus rosh", which ultimately will bring them both to erva!!
How on earth do you explain this?

https://www.sefaria.org/Derekh_Chayyim.3.13.4

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18931/21 "kalus rosh" means "disinhibited behavior." Any sort of weakening of inhibitions or self-control can lead to bad things.

I want to add to my question.   As shalom said it can lead to bad things. Objectively we can understand that being a big joker can make a person treat many prohibitions lightly.  But the prohibition of ervah specifically is not the 1st thing I would think of. It may be the last.   I know plenty of jokers. And I believe that they would take loshon horas less seriously. Perhaps they would take mussar less serious. But why why why ervah? That is such a puzzle.     Can anyone tell me of a story brought down in seforim or a personal story that supports this.  It's so unfathomable to my experience

What is "kitzur middos"? I've never heard that term before.

Mesillat Yesharim ch. 5 (in translation): "For even though sexual immorality is regarded as severe by every man of faith, and his heart fears approaching it, due to the vivid picture that has been imprinted in his mind of the enormity of the sin and the severe punishment it incurs, nevertheless, laughter and light-headedness draw him on little by little, advancing him nearer till the fear of sin leaves him bit by bit, degree after degree, until he reaches the sin itself and commits it."

"The poskim there (YD 195:1) talk about all sorts of innocuous games like chess and ping-pong as examples of kallus rosh" which poskim?

Did you invent the term "kitzur middos"?

"kitzur middos" is an erroneous edit. I originally wrote without commas "... Taught by the kitzur (comma) middos". I am referring to siman 29 in the kitzur after he is done with hashkomas haboker and tefilla and begins to discuss Talmud Torah and the way to go about your life with the correct balance in all middos

Executive Summary:

שְׂחוֹק - being focused on non-productive activities,
וְקַלּוּת רֹאשׁ - or letting one's mind be filled with opinions without filtering the input,
מַרְגִּילִין לְעֶרְוָה - primes one to become more open to anti-Torah behavior.


The source of this "suggestion" of the Kitzur is in Avos 3:13:

רַבִּי עֲקִיבָא אוֹמֵר, שְׂחוֹק וְקַלּוּת רֹאשׁ, מַרְגִּילִין לְעֶרְוָה.‏

Before explaining what the words mean, let's use the approach of the דרך החיים to this Mishna, by looking at the previous Mishna:

רַבִּי יִשְׁמָעֵאל אוֹמֵר, הֱוֵי קַל לְרֹאשׁ

Here רַבִּי יִשְׁמָעֵאל is teaching us that when dealing with a "senior" - a רֹאשׁ - one should be easygoing, and open-minded when hearing their opinions. So קַל לְרֹאשׁ and קַלּוּת רֹאשׁ seem to mean allowing one's opinions to be influenced without critically analyzing their worth or truth.
That's a good thing when dealing with a Torah personality. Otherwise it's highly troublesome.
This is confirmed by the מסילת ישירים in Ch. 5 who explains that the opposite of זְּהִירוּת - controlling and being aware of one's thoughts - is קלות ראש which leads to שחוק and is a slippery slope which, when left unchecked, leads to promiscuity.
As an added bonus we can use definitions of the Jastrow kindly provided by Sefaria in our Mishna. Picking and choosing:

שְׂחוֹק: laughter, sport, jest ... the sport here mentioned means idolatry, debauchery, and bloodshed.
קַלּוּת רֹאשׁ: light-mindedness, irreverence, disregard of custom.
מַרְגִּילִין: to accustom one’s self, get used to, to bring about; cause.
עֶרְוָה: nakedness, shame; unchastity, lewdness, obscenity.

So, putting all the above together the Kitzur or the Mishna seem to say:

שְׂחוֹק - being focused on non-productive activities,
וְקַלּוּת רֹאשׁ - or letting one's mind be filled with opinions without filtering the input,
מַרְגִּילִין לְעֶרְוָה - primes one to become more open to anti-Torah behavior.

Clearly, this is individual.
If you play chess to sharpen your analytical skills, that will help in your Talmud studies.
If you play chess as an excuse to be in a smoke-filled room with anti-Torah banter, the next step is to be invited to a backroom for some sinful behavior.
If you play ping-pong as an elegant way to stay fit and improve your focus, that's going to help you become a better Jew.
If you play ping-pong as a way to impress young ladies, then מַרְגִּילִין לְעֶרְוָה is a good description of your next move.
A similar approach can be made for using the internet:
If you use the internet for quick access to seemingly unlimited access to quality Torah, that's commendable.
But if you use the internet for quick access to free entertainment - שְׂחוֹק - or for accessing  opinions of people who do not need to account for their behavior nor source their opinions - קַלּוּת רֹאשׁ - then you're inching closer to ruining your life, as it says: מַרְגִּילִין לְעֶרְוָה
And this is why the Kitzur uses רַבִּי עֲקִיבָא as a support for the previous admonition:

לֹא יְהֵא אָדָם בַּעַל שְׂחוֹק וּמַהֲתָלוֹת, וְלֹא עָצֵב וְאוֹנֵן אֶלָּא שָׂמֵחַ.‏

A person should not be a jokester nor a prankster, nor sad and mournful; just be happy.
Being a jokester or a prankster means you and your audience are being distracted from focusing on important things in life.

Thank you for this.  But it's exactly the answer I was not looking for. Because it a bit of a rewrite of the translation of ervah. Nobody has been able to give me a peshat in this mishna that I'm looking for that would preserve the translation of ervah being quite literally sexual immorality. Of all the middos of my own that I would like to change, sechok and kallus rosh are the last ones and ervah is the last reason for eradicating this mida in my humble opinion...

Yes, we are living in times where we cannot see how devastating playing chess is, to our neshama, due to yeridat hadorot.

Imagine a brand new, white garment: spotless and pristine. Even a single tiny stain on it is glaring and devastating. Now compare that to a garment already covered in mud and grime. Adding another smudge doesn't make much of a difference—it’s already dirty.

The Lubavitcher Rebbe, in a sicha (I can't remember which, he has decades of sichot), he paints a clear picture. The dor hamidbar were on such a holy level, that the idea of them speaking lashon hara in the way we do nowadays with slander, insults, and slurs, is unthinkable.
So, when the Torah talks about the punishment for these people for speaking Lashon Hara (tzara'at, "leprosy"), the Torah says "when a man {adam} has a discoloration on his skin he will be brought to the Aharon the Cohen... [Vayikra 13:2]". The Rebbe points out that it uses the word "adam", which is indeed the highest complement Torah gives to man, describing him as a Godly being, similar (adame) to God. Such a being would never be nasty like this.
The Rebbe concludes that the "sin" of Lashon Hara at the time of the dor hamidbar was for making frivolous speech. Nothing more. Not even a joke, just talking about empty, mundane matters. That's when they were given the "reward" of tzara'at - an early warning sign that you are engaging in an activity that makes a small stain on your pristine soul. Keep up this activity and soon your whole soul will be black.

First you discuss empty matters.
Then you make jokes about empty matters.
Then you make jokes about holy matters.
Then holy matters become a joke to you.
Next thing you know, you are speaking nasty Lashon Hara so regularly that the Chafetz Chaim foundation needs to start a movement to simply get you to keep the most basic halachot of not being nasty in your speech about your fellow Jew.
(and onward up to 365) All sins become permissable.

The Torah cares about you too much to lie to you. Even though playing chess is only 1 or 2 on the ladder, it is a wrong ladder, every rung taking you one step closer to a nasty place, leaving more and more muck on your boot, your hands, your clothes. The Torah cares about you too much to say "it's ok to climb on steps 1 or 2 of the ladder, just don't go to steps 3 or 4 or 5".
Any steps on a filthy ladder is a sin to your pristine soul. Hashem doesn't let. The only reason contemporary halacha, and eitza from Rabbonim is permissive and allows us to play chess in moderation is because of rachmanut and acknowledgement of the reality of yeridat hadorot; we are already way above rung 5 on the ladder, and it's exhausting us. It's exhausting to be so filthy, and so disconnected from the true holiness inherent in our soul. It's a provision, a lesser-of-two-evils, a bedi'eved heter.
Let them at least play chess a bit, to help them find the strength to work on climbing down the ladder.
When we get lower, we will not find it so ridiculous - such a joke - that chess is an issue. We might actually start to agree with Hashem at that point*. May Moshiach come and teach us these amazing holy realities bimhera beyamenu. Until then play chess, in moderation, and think thoughts of Teshuva if you can.
tl;dr Any sin becomes possible, including the extreme sins of arayot, once we climb the ladder of letzanut high enough, and every frivolity is a rung on this same ladder. We are just so high on that ladder in today's generation that we can't relate to that, but we must trust the wise words of the Torah, and try to climb down the ladder one step at a time.
* In this video, the Rabbi says a phrase about cell (mobile) phones that stuck with me: "we get to the point of dependence on our phone for dopamine, that we can be literally sitting with our family, the people we love most in the world, but we have to pull out our phone  because it's not enough dopamine."... When stated so starkly, it's impossible to not realise that yes, we do have an issue. Why do we need chess? Surely there are much more fulfilling things to do with our precious time on earth... It may be hard to relate to, but it's not a joke. It's quite sad actually. Have rachmanus on your soul.

I am looking for poshut peshat in the middos of the kitzur shulchan oruch.  This is all a very indirect casualty.  And there's a million other things that also contribute to bringing a person to ervah.   The kitzur must be referring to a direct correlation between this sechok and ervah.  And even if you say that chess is not kallus rosh and instead replace excessive letzonus and joking about all things serious, it would still fail to explain how that has any direct connection to ervah.
